# Updating color values in 3D array for picture

Tags: java, arrays, colors, pixel

I have an array in Java called pic[400][400][3]

I put that array in a method that makes it into an image.

Before I call the method to make the array into a picture, I want to change the color values for each pixel. I am struggling with the concept of how to select the value I want to alter and then what I need to enter to adjust the color values in the array. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pic[xcoord][ycoord][0]` would be red.

`pic[xcoord][ycoord][1]` would be blue.

`pic[xcoord][ycoord][2]` would be green.

This would be easier, however, with a `BufferedImage`. There is `getRGB()`, `setRGB()`, and it supports alpha values. It is also a lot easier to save and load images.